"featured questions - bounty" feature
i fear that this feature of adding a bounty may not work very well...  it appears that all it does is add it to the 'featured question' section of the screen.  but , i dont think many users would be aware of that section of the screen.  as if they were , then they would jump to answer and reap the bounty!
therefore rather than being just in the featured question section, i suggest that it should be in the normal questions view , but placed AT THE TOP so it is straight away visible to everyone
